# I am trying to get number of records of excel file on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form in which I want to upload an excel sheet, when I choose the file I want to show the number of records of the file, before uploading the excel file. Is it possible by ajax?

Comment: u need to upload it to server 1st, and then from server to ur web, because you can't direct read local file from js

Comment: You may use libraries like https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Comment: Are you sure we can not read file on client side??

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Se0ng11 is right. On client side, there is no way to parse the file you are uploading. It is security rule and there is no way to get around. File selected in form you can just send to backend. Nothing more.